# Jquery Javascript. Function not working on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

This could be kind of complex cause there is a lot of ravioli code involved. I'm just looking for possible causes of this behavior.

Im using Jquery [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), it works correctly. The only thing that is not working is a function that I call when the document is ready, why could that be? :

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

        $('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.element-item',
          layoutMode: 'packery',

          packery: {
            gutter: 10
          }
        });

        var isotopeFilter = function(f){
            console.log(f);
            $(".grid").isotope({filter: f});
        }

        isotopeFilter('.xp');  // Doesn't Work!!

        $("#filter-basket").on("click", function(){
            isotopeFilter('.basket');  // Works correctly
            });

        $("#filter-all").on("click", function(){
            $(".grid").isotope({ filter: '.xp' });  // Works correctly
        });

        $("#filter-ghacking").on("click", function(){
            $(".grid").isotope({ filter: '.ghacking' });  // Works correctly
        });
    })
```

The reason I need to call that function at document load is because I want to set a default filtering.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working?" Is it not being called, is it behaving not as expected, is it erroring?

Comment: is it possible this script is being loaded before jquery is being loaded?

Comment: @Jacob It doesn't "filter" the elements as it is supposed to. It works only after the "click" events.

Comment: @QBM5 I load isotope immediately after jquery. I still suspect something like this might be the cause of the error.

Comment: I wasnt asking about isotope, I was asking about the file that contains your $(document).ready() function

Comment: Oh, ok yes that script is loaded at the end